# Drupal - Theme the uc_upsell module?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

On my ubercart installation I am using the uc_upsell block to display related products. The block is working fine, but I would like to customise the template of it to rearrange the fields and add new sections in etc. E.g. I'd like the product title to appear above the image.

Is this possible and if so how would I do it?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little bit of a hack because you arent supposed to modify modules but you can always go into the ***uc_upsell.module*** file and find the code on lines 236-239 starting with // Linked title

Move those four lines to right under  `$output = '';` which is on line 223 and you are good to go. I am sure other people will improve this comment by showing how to do this in the template.tpl.php file but this answer will suit your purposes until there is an module update